# with 20.04 my HP laptop occasionly hangs after closing the lid and reopening later - I have to force power off

Tags: 20.04, laptop

After reopening the lid the screen shows the suspend screen that says "press any key to continue". When the lid is opened I can't wake the computer with any combination of key presses, I have to force the computer of using the power key and then use the power key to restart. Only happens occasionally, every 3 days or so. I've only had 20.04 installed a month or so and it was a new install on a new laptop.

This an HP with the following config; Ubuntu 20.04.2, AMD Ryzen 7 4700 with Radon Graphics, HP motherboard 8707 and solid state storage.

Comment: I'm not familiar with seeing a "press any key to continue" appearing if I suspend so I don't know what you describe, but I can't see why you couldn't switch to terminal and correct a likely *stuck* GUI, or even if that was impossible, that SysRq commands direct to the kernel wouldn't allow a far safer shutdown than using the power-key (it also provides very useful information as it tells you the kernel is still up & running, it may only be the display/GUI that is locked/stuck).  Did you try those before you resorted to power-off?

Comment: There are no keys that will unlock it. I didn't specifically try Alt-Crtl + T, but I tried Alt- ctrl-delete with no effect. I'll try the terminal command next time but it doesn't appear to recognize any keys, thanks.

Comment: Well, I guess that I'm actually going backwards. This time the screen was black and no combination of keys would wake it up, I only know it was powered up because the power light was on. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+Del was a MS-DOS command that caused reset, and I didn't think you were using DOS but a Ubuntu system (yes it was used for some versions of windows in some circumstances only). I also didn't mention Ctrl+Alt+T which won't work if you have a stuck GUI as it's a GUI related command. Ctrl+Alt+F4 or switching to a text terminal is what I was talking about which isn't related to a GUI so a gui/crash/freeze should not impact it; nor should a SysRq command which goes direct to the kernel (it'd work on my Android phone if only my android phone had a real keyboard attached)

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.2 and ALT-Ctrl+Del will allow you to Log out but the system is not responding to any keys. I'll try Alt-Ctrl + F4 and see if that will drop me into the command line. Thanks for your help.

Comment: FYI: The system is responding to keys as you say Ctrl+Alt+F4 worked; likewise SysRq commands will work...   It's not the system that is stuck, but only your GUI that is stuck, and why the most common SysRq command REISUB has the R as the first character; ie. it takes back control from a stuck X/GUI. If you don't remember the sysrq commands; a search on a phone for "magic sysrq" will usually give you the wikipedia article which is pretty good  (applies to any Linux device, not just Ubuntu)

Comment: Actually Ctrl-Alt + F4 DOES NOT WORK. I think I need to report this as a bug in 20.04.2 as the system does not respond to any keys or mouse clicks, my only alternative is to force the power off.

Comment: I covered both Ctrl+Alt+F4 & SysRq commands; the SysRq commands are different, do not require login & will function even if you have a stuck GUI or cannot use Ctrl+Alt+F4 to switch to text terminal -- they allow you to directly command the linux kernel and it's what I'd do as already stated.  Lack of response to keys & mouse-clicks only means the GUI is stuck; did SysRq commands work?  ie. is the kernel still running?